# Relative path issue within Sinatra view

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am using the following code to check existence of a file before publishing an image in my erb file.  This is a ruby/sinatra app - not rails.

```
<% @imagename = @place.name + ".jpg" %> 
<% if FileTest.exist?( "/Users/Tim/projects/game/public/" + @imagename ) %> 
<p><img src= '<%= @imagename %>' width="400" height="300" /> </p> 
<% end %>
```

And when I publish this to Heroku, it obviously won't work.

I tried using a relative path, but I'm unable to get it to work:

```
<% if FileTest.exist?( "/" + @imagename ) %>
```

Answer (score 9):

A path starting with a `/` is not a relative path, that's an absolute path. It says *go to the root and then navigate down to the following path*

The first step is to check where your app is running from. i.e. what is the current directory. To do this temporarily put `<%= Dir.pwd %>` in your view and try this both locally and on Heroku to compare the two environments.

Then try a relative path from this folder to the image. e.g. If the app is running from `/Users/Tim/projects/game` then the relative path to public is just `public` so the path to the image would be `File.join('public', @imagename)`

If you need more help then please post the value of `Dir.pwd` from both environments

---

**Here is another approach:**

`__FILE__` is a special Ruby variable that gives a relative path to the current file.

Making use of that, in the .rb file that starts your app set a constant as follows:

```
APP_ROOT = File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

(a similar line in an app's config.rb is used to set `RAILS_ROOT` in a Rails app)

Then in your view you can use:

```
FileTest.exist?(File.join(APP_ROOT, 'public', @imagename))
```

Comment: Updated for Sinatra above. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This approach worked:
"Then try a relative path from this folder to the image. e.g. If the app is running from /Users/Tim/projects/game then the relative path to public is just public so the path to the image would be File.join('public', @imagename)"

The APP_ROOT approach game me an unitilized constant error.  now working.  thanks MikeJ!

Comment: Cool. glad it's working now. To get the constant to work it might just need a bit of tweaking for the specifics of your app.

Answer (score 0):

<del>What you want to is use the `RAILS_ROOT` constant - it points to your app's folder. So on your local machine `RAILS_ROOT` will evaluate to `/Users/Tim/projects/game/`.</del>

This is Rails specific, use `File.dirname(__FILE__)` instead.

Comment: This was clarified after the solution was posted. In this case `File.dirname(__FILE__)` would probably do the trick.